# Auto Slider Speed up on Button Hover [simplyScroll v2]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, simplyscroll

I'm working on a Slider for my website. It all works well but I want it to speed up when I hover over 2 buttons on the left and right. I couldn't figure out yet how to make it work.
Plugin site: http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

**NOTE:** I need something like the combination of the automatic one and the button one presented on that website.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="scroller">
    <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080514_JYW68XPT_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li>
    <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080514_JYW68XPT_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Chloe nightclub"></li>
    <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080514_JYW68XPT_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse bar"></li>
    <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080514_B1YJ08B6_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse chloe club fishtank"></li>
    <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080514_JYW68XPT_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse restaurant"></li>
    <li><img src="http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/assets/20080608_38CG51J2_tb.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Firehouse"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#scroller").simplyScroll({pauseOnHover: true});
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Just make two button and bind them to a jquery **hover** and specify the **speed** attribute of the function. Check out the example here http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal_manual.html

Comment: tried it couldnt get it to work

Comment: It will be more clear if you can prepare a fiddle for your code and then ask specific questions.